# Creating friendlier URLs in an ASP.NET WebForm application

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, webforms

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application. What I am trying to do is create dynamic friendly URLs using `RewritePath`. What I want to be able to do is grab the subdomain of the URL coming in, check a table in my database called `Domains` and then depending on the subdomain, rewrite the url adding a query string of `?id=1` or whatever the `id` is.

In addition, I would like the path to determine the page to load. So for example:

```
http://www.mysite.com should go to                --> http://www.mysite.com/Default.aspx
http://dog.mysite.com should go to                --> http://www.mysite.com/MainPage.aspx?id=1
http://cat.mysite.com should go to                --> http://www.mysite.com/MainPage.aspx?id=2
http://cat.mysite.com?p=15 should go to           --> http://www.mysite.com/MainPage.aspx?id=2&p=15
http://cat.mysite.com/OtherPage should go to      --> http://www.mysite.com/OtherPage.aspx?id=2
http://cat.mysite.com/OtherPage?p=15 should go to --> http://www.mysite.com/OtherPage.aspx?id=2&p=15
```

Hopefully the examples give you the idea that I am looking for. I would prefer to be able to do this from the global.asax file because I do not have access to the IIS web server machine to be able to install some server-side module for URL rewriting.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this blog of ScuttGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)  it talks about url renaming in details.